# NSUserNotification with attributed strings

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsusernotification

I would like to know if it is possible to have an `NSUserNotification` with `NSAttributedString`'s ?

My requirement is to have some text in bold.

Comment: there is not way for that